# testing web under various resolutions

Tags: html, css, resolution, screen-resolution

I'm creating a web site and need to ensure it looks the same across resolutions and screen sizes.  Right now, it looks fine on my laptops.  When I have others look at it, it does not look fine (even if they have the same resolution as me but different monitor size).  How can I test for both resolution and monitor size differences (both mac and windows)?  I know for a resolution I can just change it on my windows.  As I said though, this looks fine on my screen at various resolutions but it will not look good on other computers with the same resolution (but different screen sizes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are just a few of several tools available:

- http://quirktools.com/screenfly/
- http://resizemybrowser.com/
- http://responsivepx.com/
- http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

Answer (score 0):

Try http://browsershots.org/ this makes screenshots of your website on different browsers, there's also a "Screen Size" drop down.